# Click area of button overlapping click area of adjacent button

Tags: javascript, html, css, telerik

I'm having issues with the click area of an `input type='file'` overlapping the click area of another button. I'm making use of ***RadUpload*** which is a part of ***Telerik*** (I'm aware *RadUpload* is depreciated and *RadAsyncUpload* is the replacement, but I need to use *RadUpload*). My code looks like the following (which is using webforms RadUpload controls to generate this HTML):

CSS:

```
.RadUpload .ruFileWrap {
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 20px;
    zoom: 1;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    display: inline !important;
    height: 24px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li>
    <span class = "ruFileWrap ruStyled">
        <input type="file" name="ctl00_ContentMain_uplUserReferenceBatchFilefile0" id="ctl00_ContentMain_uplUserReferenceBatchFilefile0" size="23" class="ruFileInput" style="width: 202px;">
        <label for="ctl00_ContentMain_uplUserReferenceBatchFilefile0" style="display: none;">label</label>
        <input type="text" class="ruFakeInput" id="ctl00_ContentMain_uplUserReferenceBatchFileTextBox0" size="22" title="">
        <label for="ctl00_ContentMain_uplUserReferenceBatchFileTextBox0" style="display: none;">label</label>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="Browse" class="ruButton ruBrowse">
        <input type="submit" class="ruButton" value="Submit" width="10" name="ctl00_ContentMain_uplUserReferenceBatchFilesubmit1" id="ctl00_ContentMain_uplUserReferenceBatchFilesubmit1">
    </span>
</li>
```

I believe the issue lies within the styling of CSS class `.ruFileInput` since when I hover over the element in *Chrome Developer Tools* a large area outside of the UI widgets are highlighted - see attached screenshot.

[image: OverlappingBrowseClickArea]

When I click on the submit button the popup to select a file is opened - this is not desired functionality - the popup should only occur if the file textbox or browse is clicked.

Any help with this issue would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you try to remove inline styles of the  style="width: 202px;" of the first input type="text" with name ( **ctl00_ContentMain_uplUserReferenceBatchFilefile0** ) element?

Comment: Thank you for you answer @PrasadGayan but unfortunately it didn't fix the issue. Removing this inline styling extended the click area from the submit button to the far left of the page (became 1885 x 132).

Any other ideas?

Comment: it seems its using another styles, so just try to set the width and height of above input , as same as the size size of the button ( probably lower proposition than before). also try to get the button size from even another button which looks like same width & height

Comment: I set the height and width the same as that input but the click area now appears slightly above the submit button instead of over the Browse button. I've tried adding a margin right to the input to attempt to force the click area above the browse button but the unwanted area remains clickable unfortunately.